# How to call ReadFile() in Kernal32.dll Asynchronously? C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, asynchronous, usb

I am trying to read data from a device that is connected via the USB port.

To Achieve this I am using the following function,

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
internal static extern bool ReadFile
    (
        IntPtr hFile,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] [Out] byte[] lpBuffer,
        uint nNumberOfBytesToRead,
        out uint lpNumberOfBytesRead,
        [In] ref System.Threading.NativeOverlapped lpOverlapped
    );
```

However this function call is blocking my UI thread and causing my UI to appear to hang up while the read is being executed.

I read on MSDN that the RedFile can be run Asynchronously in [C++ ReadFile() MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx). I read about ReadFile() [on C# MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d9wy99d.aspx) and it doesn't explain anything about Asynchronous execution.

I have tried adding the standard changes to try to make it Asynchonous but I get an error, "Cannot marshal 'return value': Generic types cannot be marshaled" I believe this is because I changed the return type of the function call to `Task<bool>`. And the return parameter is of type `unmanagedType.Bool`.

Comment: *I have tried adding the standard changes to try to make it Asynchonous but I get an error, "Cannot marshal 'return value': Generic types cannot be marshaled" I believe this is because I changed the return type of the function call to Task<bool>* And you did **wrong**. You simply changed the signature of a method of which you don't have the body and hoped some magic fairy would have made some magic. Sadly no magic for you.

Comment: @xanatos Yeah exactly, was hoping for some magic since I had no access to the body of the method... unfortunate Christmas only comes once a year and Santa couldnt make an early delivery just for me.

Answer (score -1):

In order to do Asynchronous I/O with ReadFile() you need to use the Overlapped structure. You usually want your asynchronous I/O on a separate thread and then to wake/signal you when the I/O has completed.  There are a number of ways you can do this, but on Windows it's usually done with an event.

Read this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365683(v=vs.85).aspx